# Extract numeric value from string in Cloudwatch to use in metrics (e.g. "64MB")

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Is it possible to create a metric that extracts a numeric value from a string in Cloudwatch logs so I can graph / alarm it?

For example, the log may be:
20190827 1234 class: File size: 64MB

I realize I can capture the space delimited fields by using a filter pattern like: [date, time, class, word1, word2, file_size]

And file_size will be "64MB", but how do I convert that to a numeric 64 to be graphed?

Bonus question, is there any way of matching "File size:" as one field instead of creating a field for each space delimited word?

Answer (score 3):

Use `abs` to cast to number, or any other numberic function

**Using Glob Expressions**

```
fields @message
| parse @message "File size: *MB" as size
| filter abs(size)<64
| limit 20
```

**Using Regular Expressions**

```
fields @message
| parse @message /File size:\s+(?<size>\d+)MB/
| filter abs(size)<64
| limit 20
```

To learn how glob or regular expression can be used, see [Cloud Watch Logs Query Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with metric filters that the question is about. There is no doubt Logs Insights have powerful query language but the question was about extracting a value from a log to create a metric, which is different.